# Do you know why is appearing the error: GET 500 (Internal Server Error)? (Ajax get request)

Tags: php, laravel

I have following code the view to list the cities that exist for all conferences stored in a database.

For example, if there are 2 conference entries in the database and one  has the city Newcastle, another has the city Leeds it should show in this modal Newcastle and Leeds -

```
<ul class="modal-list">
    @foreach($cities as $city)
        <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <a  class="" name="city" id="{{$city}}">{{$city}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

When the user click in some city it appears this error:

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://proj.test/conferences/where/city/Newcastle 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

When the user clicks in some city is done an ajax request to get the conferences that have the column "city" equal to the city clicked by the user:

```
$("a[name='city']").on('click', function(){


                var city = $(this).attr("id");


                $.ajax({

                    url: '{{ route('city.conferences',null) }}/' + city,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success:function(result){
                        console.log(result)

                        alert(result);
                        $('#conferences').empty();
                        var newConferences='';
                        var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";
                        $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                            var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);

                            newEvens += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
                                '                        <div class="card box-shaddow">\n' +
                                '                            <img class="card-img-top" src='+ conference.image +' alt="Card image cap">\n' +
                                '                            <div class="card-body">\n' +
                                '                                <p class="font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>  '+conference.start_date+'</p>\n' +
                                '                                <h5 class="card-title h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue">'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
                                '                                <p class="card-text font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+conference.place+', '+conference.city+'</p>\n' +
                                '                            </div>\n' +
                                '                           <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">\n' +
                                '                                 <a href="' + url + '" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>' +
                                ' <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-sm"></span>\n'
                            '                           </div>\n' +
                            '                    </div>';
                        });

                        $('#conferences').html(newConferences);

                    },
                    error: function(error) {

                        console.log(error.status)
                    }

                });

            });
```

Route:

ConferenceController getConferencesOfCity route:

```
Route::get('conferences/where/city/{slug}','ConferenceController@getConferencesOfCity')->name('city.conferences');
```

ConferenceController getConferencesOfCity method:

```
public function getConferencesOfCity(Request $request)
    {
        $conferences = Conference::whereCity('city', DB::raw($request->slug))->get();

        return response()->json($conferences);
    }
```

Do you know why I see the error?

Comment: Check your logs in `/storage/logs` for more information on why you're getting a 500.

Comment: Thanks, it appears {message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found",…}, with "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;" now appears:

[]
No properties. Do  you know why?

Comment: This "        $conferences = Conference::whereCity('city', DB::raw($request->slug))->get();
" returns Collection {#258
  #items: []
}.

Comment: If you're now getting an empty array as a response, you probably aren't getting any results. You can check by adding `Log::info($request->slug);` and `Log::info($conferences->toArray());` in your controller, then check  that same log.

Comment: Thanks, both are null.

Comment: Your query is also slightly wrong. Since you're using `whereCity()`, you don't specify the column. Also unless you're passing along MySQL functions or more difficult queries, `DB::raw` is not needed. Instead, use `Conference::whereCity($request->slug)->get();`

Comment: Thanks, like that it works. But the cities appear in a modal and now when a city is clicked it appears:
[{id: 7, name: "test name", city: "Newcastle",…} in the network tab. But the modal is not closed, but if the modal is manually closed the conferences that have the column city equal to the clicked city dont appear in the #conferences div, any conference appears on the #conferences div.

Comment: You're appending to `newEvens`, instead of `newConferences`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to change here:

1) You need to pass the variable slug that you're getting from the route into the constructor of the function. Request isn't needed since you're not doing anything else with it.

2) You're already using `whereCity`, so don't pass in the column name

3) `DB::raw` is really only needed for more complicated queries or passing in mysql functions

```
public function getConferencesOfCity($slug)
    {
        $conferences = Conference::whereCity($slug)->get();

        return response()->json($conferences);
    }
```

Comment: For example if the user click in the city "Newcastle" it appears two conferences in the #conferences div. The issue is that when there are more than 1 conference there is a issue, the second conference appears inside the div "card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" of the first conference instead of appear next to each other. Do you know why?

Comment: You're not closing out one of the divs. Add an extra close div. You can double-check how things are formatted by looking at the rendered html.

Comment: Thanks, I add that but same issue. It appears like "https://jsfiddle.net/yh8bzyfr/1/", the second confernece "<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">" appears inside the first conference "div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">".

Comment: It might be because you're missing a plus sign after `' <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-sm"></span>\n'`

Comment: Thanks, it was that!